# Cross Join for Missing table (Select all and Select or Insert the Missing Row Only)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two table and have to fill in a list of missing values in one of the table based on the other one. First table has student's information and the second table has Grade related info, Grade and Grade description.

Table One

```
ID    Name    yearWithUs       Grade     Course Level
1     Jim     2004             4          4
2     Jim     2004             4          1
2     Jim     2003             3          3
4     Jim     2002             2          3
4     Jim     2002             2          1
3     Jim     2001             1          2
3     Jim     2001             1          1
```

Table two -- logic is.. A Student in a higher Course Level can change to a lower Course Level at anytime during the semester. And It can only go downward 1 level at a time. Example: Jim in his second grade first was assigned to attend course in level 3. He need to attend course in level 2 first before he can attend course in level 1. Means. Row for course level 2 at jim's first grade is missing.

Table Two

```
ID    Grade      Grade_Desc        Course Level    Course Desc
1     1          First Grade          1              Basic
2     1          First Grade          2              Normal
3     1          First Grade          3              Hard
4     1          First Grade          4              Expert
5     2          Second Grade         1
6     2          Second Grade         2 
7     2          Second Grade         3
8     2          Second Grade         4
.     .             .
.     .             .
.     .             .
```

Logic of Table Two

```
ID    Grade      Grade_Desc        Course Level    Possible Move
1     1          First Grade          1              Null
2     1          First Grade          2              1   
3     1          First Grade          3              2 
4     1          First Grade          4              3
```

Ouptput one ... how to use select statement to return Jim's Grade?

```
ID    Name    Grade_Desc            Grade     yerWithUs    Course Level
1     Jim    Fourth Grade           4           2004            4
2     Jim    Fourth Grade           4           2004            3
3     Jim    Fourth Grade           4           2004            2
4     Jim    Fourth Grade           4           2004            1
5     Jim    Third Grade            3           2003            3
6     Jim    Second Grade           2           2002            3
7     Jim    Second Grade           2           2002            2
8     Jim    Second Grade           2           2002            1
9     Jim    First Grade            2           2001            2
10    Jim    First Grade            2           2001            1
```

Output Two..How to retrieve only the missing row into a new temp table?

```
ID    Name    Grade_Desc            Grade     yearWithUs   Course Level
2     Jim    Fourth Grade           4           2004            3
3     Jim    Fourth Grade           4           2004            2
7     Jim    Second Grade           2           2002            2
```

I am currently is using a messy Cursor Statement to do it. The structure looks really messy and hard to debug return errors. I did a lot of research, and saw people use Cross Join to fill the missing portion which looks really clean (See example below)... I have tried the script it myself in many different way by using the cross join example below...obviously, I failed. I found a similar question in stackoverflow..but I am not able to understand how does it work and why without looking at the data....I need help to understand how to use cross join to rerun missing row? and I am open to any other possible solution.

```
 "SELECT  calendar.Date,
         Category.Cat,
         Score = ISNULL(Scores.Score, 0)
  FROM   Calendar
         CROSS JOIN Catogory
    LEFT JOIN Scores
        ON Scores.Cat = Category.Cat
        AND Scores.Date = Calendar.Date
    WHERE   Calendar.DayOfMonth = 1;"
```

[Inserting missing rows with a join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202852/inserting-missing-rows-with-a-join)

Thank You

Comment: Did you miss tommy 2010?  What does ?//2 mean? Make your output exactly what it should be according to your input data. Where does second table come in play?

Comment: Means I want that column to be 2..updating my output

Comment: Dont you want to answer other questions? Why it should be 2? Logic?

Comment: In the output. I want to have three fields: Name, Grade_Desc, Grade. Name and Grade are in the first table. Gtade_Desc is in the second table. In the first table, it is missing Grade#1,3,5 for Jim, #2,3,5 for Tommy, #1,2,3,4 for Terry.... I want to script a query to filled them in

Comment: Table names and column names in you query don't match the information above.   Return Tommy is actually Jim.  What is logic of table 2?   What is score?

Comment: @Blam you are correct. That's a typo. Table two was joined by two tables, grade table and course level table. The logic is no make sense in reality, but that's one of the requirements. there are 4 course levels for each grade. Student will take course level at the beginning of a semester for the default course level. During the semester, a student can downgrade his course one level at a time, but it can only go forward, cannot jump back to a higher level. If Jim wants to go to course level 2 when he is in course level4 program, he has to attend course level 3 before attending level 2.

Comment: Score? I don't use score

Comment: @Blam I have fixed the typo issue. I updated my questions and tables. That's why it doesn't much my earlier replied

Comment: Not you have not.   The query names do not match the table nor column names.   Show some effort.

Answer (score 0):

This will produce that output:

```
select distinct name, grade, Grade_Desc 
  from one 
 cross join two
```

Answer (score 0):

If select is all you want then:

```
Select row_number() over(order by (select 1)) as id, * from
(Select distinct name from t1)t1
cross join t2
```

Here is fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a8a42/3

Comment: Could you also show to do an insert, and how to retrieve the missing row only? Much appreciate

Comment: Giorgi, I edited my question with a more complicate question that I was under-thinking before. Your sqlfiddle example gave me some light in dark to understand how to return unique values by using cross join. But I am looking for more actually. I would be appreciated if you could help me out with the update question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

### Create #Temp

```
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(100) = 'Jim'

SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY B.Grade DESC,B.CourseLevel DESC) ID,
        A.Name,
        B.Grade_Desc,
        B.Grade,
        A.YearWithUs,
        B.[Course Level] 
INTO #temp
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Name,YearWithUs,Grade
    FROM TableOne
    WHERE Name = @Name
) A
INNER JOIN TableTwo B
ON A.Grade = B.Grade
```

### Output One

```
SELECT *
FROM #temp
```

### Output Two into #OutputTwo(temp table)

```
SELECT A.* INTO #OutputTwo
FROM #temp A
LEFT JOIN TableOne B
ON A.Grade = B.Grade
AND A.[Course Level] = B.[Course Level]
WHERE A.Grade IS NULL AND A.[Course Level] IS NULL
```