# Hive LAG function - year over year change - to get previous value even if there is no current vaue

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql, lag

I am calculating year over year change and below is the query in hive

```
    select Name, 
    Year, 
    Month, 
    ID,
    value as Current, 
    LAG(value,1,0) OVER(PARTITION BY name,month,id ORDER BY year ASC) as Previous, 
    value - LAG(value,1,0) OVER(PARTITION BY name,month,id ORDER BY year ASC) as Change
```

Current Result

```
    Name    Year    Month   ID  Current     Previous        Change
    A       2015    1       8320    944     0               944
    O       2015    1       8320    153     0               153
    O       2016    1       8320    133.92  153             -19.08
    B       2015    1       8320    572     0               572
    C       2016    1       8320    126     0               126
```

There are 3 cases for the year 2016

1. Name O - Has both values for 2016 and 2015 and I get difference
2. Name C - Has value only in 2016 and I get the difference keeping 2015 as 0
3. Name A and B - Has values only in 2015 and not in 2016 - So I need to get two entries with change as -944 and -572 for A and B respectively.

My expected result is:

```
    Name    Year    Month   ID  Current     Previous        Change
    A       2015    1       8320    944     0               944
    A       2016    1       8320    0       944             -944
    O       2015    1       8320    153     0               153
    O       2016    1       8320    133.92  153             -19.08
    B       2015    1       8320    572     0               572
    B       2016    1       8320    0       572             -572
    C       2016    1       8320    126     0               126
```

Please guide me how to get the previous year values, even if there are no current year values.Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: So your question is not about the `lag` function, it's about how to generate missing data points in the underlying table. There are various ways to do that, the easiest being having a separate table of possible date values, in your case it's probably a table of possible (name, year, month) combinations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting missing rows with a join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202852/inserting-missing-rows-with-a-join)